# Disable Cookies on Specific Routes - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

Laravel 5.7

Hello, I have a (hopefully) fairly simple problem I can't seem to fix.

I have API routes that I have disabled the `csrf token` for, however the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie still appears to be sent ( visible in postman ).

Along with this cookie, I have `laravel_session` cookie for sessions. ( also visible in postman)

The purpose of these routes does not require either of these cookies and I wish to increase response time and save bandwidth by sending less bytes ( remove the cookies ) since the actual cookie values pretty long strings, maybe a hundred character.

Is there anyway to prevent/disable these cookies from being sent on specific routes like I can with csrf-token verify?

Thanks y'all for any possible solutions.

Please comment if you'd like to see any code from any file and I'd be glad to add.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem myself, I switched the route to a new `middleware` class that was not the default `web` (I guess the `web` middleware by default gives cookies) to a new minimal custom middleware.